# I can't remove border

Tags: html, css, image, border

I can't remove border from my images. I've tried many times with different atributes. Still see white border. If you have any suggestion what causes the problem - please explain to me. I'm kinda newbie.

```
<head>
    <style>
    img{
    border : none;
    text-decoration: none;
    }
    #forum
    {
        background:url(forum_button.png) 0px 0px no-repeat; 
        width: 300px; 
        height: 81px;

    }
    #forum:hover
    {
        background:url(forum_button.png) -300px 0px no-repeat; 
        width: 300px; 
        height: 81px;
    }
    #facebook
    {
        background:url(social_buttons.png) 0px 0px no-repeat;
        width: 29px; 
        height: 29px;
    }
    #facebook:hover
    {
        background:url(social_buttons.png) 0px -33px no-repeat;
        width: 29px; 
        height: 29px;
    }
    #twitter
    {
        background:url(social_buttons.png) -31px 0px no-repeat;
        width: 29px; 
        height: 29px;
    }
    #twitter:hover
    {
        background:url(social_buttons.png) -31px -33px no-repeat;
        width: 29px; 
        height: 29px;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body style="background:url(landing.png) no-repeat top #111111; width: 1280px; height: 1024px; border:0;">
    <a href="#"><img id="forum" /></a>
    <div id="social">
    <a href="#"><img id="facebook"></a>
    <a href="#"><img id="twitter"></a>
    </div>
```

Comment: Are you sure the img elements are the right width and height as the images you are using? :)

Comment: I would advise against using the img tag without the src attribute.

Comment: Show a screenshot and show the image itself please.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's because an img tag MUST have a src="" with a proper link otherwise it will be showing the image as a background like in your case (because of the css on the img) and a broken image on top of it

```
="#"><img id="facebook"></
```

It's not a border, what you see is the broken image border.

If you want to keep your code, change the img tag to a div..

Comment: I think that you are basically correct.  The problem appears in Chrome and not Firefox.

Comment: Thank you. It works! :D I've changed to div and now it runs perfectly. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Change

```css
border: none;
```

to

```css
border: none !important;
```

This way it will override all the parent's declarations and thus has to work.

Answer (score 0):

maybe the border is not html given but its in your img ?

So open your image in an image program tool like photoshop and zoom to the places where the border is and have a look, if there is a border or not.

Comment: I've checked twice. No borders. I expanded canvas size to see maybe 'hidden' one but no - there is no borders in images.

Comment: Why do you integrate your img's as backgrounds and don't just set them with the src attribute in the img tag?

Answer (score 0):

That's probably because you have no `src` attribute on your `img` tags. I'd reccommend using transparent pixel as src in your case.

Answer (score 0):

- Insert Image by using img src with proper height and width.
- Use Paint or other tools to edit image.
  example.
- make sure that your original image dont have any border, if it have simply select and crop the image.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to set an icon image on a link using a background image that can be repositioned on a hover event.

The simplest way of doing this is as follows.

The HTML can be as simple as:

```
<a class="test" id="test" href="#"></a>
```

and apply the following CSS:

```
.test {
    background: beige url(http://placekitten.com/50/50) center center no-repeat;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border: none;
}
```

Apply the background image on the link (`a` tag) instead of an `img` tag, which is not needed.

See demo at: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/qAeHL/